# MySQL/PHP: How to get columns and associated data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I know I can get the column/field names from a database by using: SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tablename`...but is there a way I can get the columns returned as well as the content, so my return would be something like this:

array[0][0] = column 1 name
array[0][1] = column 2 name
array[0][2] = column 3 name

array[1][0] = column 1 row 1 value
array[1][1] = column 2 row 1 value
array[1][2] = column 3 row 1 value

...

I'm looking to build a JSON object

jsonObj = {
     item 1 { 
                              column 1 name: column 1 row 1 value, 
                              column 2 name: column 2 row 1 value,
                              column 3 name : column 3 row 1 value...

Edit: I should add that I know the field names are returned with the query results

(SELECT * FROM sometable) and if you use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
 $thisfield = $row['fieldname']; 
}
```

But how can I access them (the field names) when I do not know them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mysql_fetch_assoc - it will return

array( "name" => "value", "name2" => "value2" ... );

then use json_encode( $data )

Comment: Thanks, it was floating in my head I just couldn't remember it. You were too quick, I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept your answer... : D

Answer (score 1):

Using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or the equivalent in whatever DB library you use will provide the column names as array keys.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_result))
{
  $results[] = $row;
}
foreach ($results as $column=>$value)
{
  // loop over $column and $value
}
```